# LinkedList divide and merge in reverse order

Tags: algorithm, linked-list

I have a linked list as `1->2->3->4->5->6`

I need to change it to `1->6->2->5->3->4`

i.e.last element linked to first element, last second element linked to the second element and so on.

I used 2 pointers, one fast and one slow. Once I reach the center, I put all the elements in the second half in a stack.  [4, 5, 6]

Now, using a third pointer, I traverse the original linked list and insert node from the stack i.e. pop [6, 5, 4]

Is there any better solution than this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is optimal.
I use 2 pointers. One slow, one jump at a time and other fast, 2 jumps at a time.
Hence, I find the center and also the mid count.
Now, from the center till the end I reverse the linked list.
I have 2 linked lists now, one from start to center and other reversed from center to end.
Simply take one element from list 1 and link the element from link 2 to this and increment both the lists.
No extra space required and time complexity is O(N)